# Basic RL curcuit problem

Tags: inductor, impedance, basic

So I had an exam in basic electronics, which I passed but lost a lot of points on one seemingly easy task.
[image]

**"Through the coil is passing a current equal to \$i_L=200\sin(10^5 t + 210°)\$. If R=5 Ohms and if L=46 microH, what is the current passing through the source?"**

This is what I wrote:

[image]

Apologies for my horrible writing. I know I messed up on the impedance angle. **But I don't understand why my amplitude of source current is wrong.**
(The correct answer is \$i_E = 271,8\sin(10^5 t + 252,6°)\$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used an impedance triangle (and pythagoras) to calculate the total impedance. That technique would be used for a series RL circuit but not for a parallel combination.

To calculate the total (parallel) impedance use product/sum or 1/RT = 1/R + 1/XL

Using this method I get 3.385 angle +48degrees for the total impedance.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will assume the angular frequency is \$10^5\text{ rad/s}\$ as you state and that the \$105\$ in the problem statement is wrong.

This is a steady-state circuit so you can just use phasor math.  You know the following,

$$2\pi f = 10^5 \text{ rad/s} $$

$$X_L=2\pi f L=j4.6 \Omega$$

Letting our reference phasor be \$sin(105t)\$ then the current down into the inductor will be,

$$i_L=200∠210° A  $$

and voltage across the inductor will be,

$$u_L=X_Li_L=  920∠{-60°} V $$

We can check this using the fundamental equation of an inductor,

$$V=L\frac{di}{dt}$$

So, $$u_L=46*10^{-6}*\frac{di_L}{dt}=46*10^{-6}*20*10^6\sin(10^5t+300°) V$$

$$u_L= 920 ∠300° V$$

Note that \$300°\$ is equivalent to \$-60°\$ on a phasor diagram.

Now that you know \$u_L\$ you know the voltage across the resistor \$R\$ and the rest you can do easy enough...and the answer will be as you gave in your post.